# Variável não é encontrada em um método de operador

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, variáveis, operadores, sobrecarga

Estou estudando sobrecarga de operadores mas meu código não está compilando.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class Complexo
    {
    public:
    int real, image;

Complexo();

Complexo(int r, int i);

Complexo operator +(Complexo& c);

};

Complexo::Complexo(int r, int i) {
   real = r;
   image = i;
}

Complexo operator +(Complexo& c) {
   Complexo x();
   x.real = real + c.real;
   x.image = image + c.image;
   return x;
}

Complexo::Complexo() {};

int main() {
   Complexo c1(1, 2);
   Complexo c2(4, 4);
   Complexo c3 = c1 + c2;

   cout << "Parte real: " << c3.real << endl;
   cout << "Parte imaginária: " << c3.image << endl;
   return 0;

 }
```

Na compilação, o erro é o seguinte:

> ```
> over.cpp: In function 'Complexo operator+(Complexo&)':
> over.cpp:25: error: 'real' was not declared in this scope
> over.cpp:26: error: 'image' was not declared in this scope
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código é essencialmente cópia [disso](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-c/) ou de algum outro lugar que este site copiou ou de um lugar que copiou daí, e lá está do jeito certo:

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class Complex { 
private: 
    int real, imag; 
public: 
    Complex(int r = 0, int i = 0)  { real = r; imag = i; } 
    Complex operator + (Complex const &obj) { 
         Complex res; 
         res.real = real + obj.real; 
         res.imag = imag + obj.imag; 
         return res; 
    } 
    void print() { cout << real << " + i" << imag << endl; } 
}; 

int main() { 
    Complex c1(10, 5), c2(2, 4); 
    Complex c3 = c1 + c2;
    c3.print(); 
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5W9tIq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/OperatorOverloading). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Operator/OperatorOverloading.cpp).

Você não pode a cessar algo que não está disponível para você, então para acessar o objeto a função que se passa pelo operador tem que estar dentro da classe onde existem essas variáveis.

Comment: Então não faz sentido colocar protótipo dos métodos dentro de uma classe? eu tenho que, necessariamente, colocar todo o corpo da função dentro da classe para que os objetos envolvidos sejam acessados?

Comment: Na forma como quer, sim.